# Python - dealing with numpy functions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I was given a question: I'm given 100000 sequences of 1000 coin tosses arranged in a matrix. To generate the data use the commands:

```
import numpy

data = numpy.random.binomial(1, 0.25, (100000,1000))
```

Now I need for the first 5 sequences of 1000 tosses (the first 5 rows in data) to plot (using pylab) the estimate Xm which is the sum of i from 1 to m. (Meaning the sum of all tosses up to m)

Now I was trying to do the following:

```
data = numpy.random.binomial(1, 0.25, (100000,1000))
x = numpy.linspace(1,1000,1000, int) // in order to create an array of 1000 ints between 1 and 1000
y = numpy.sum(data[0], x) // taking the first row
pylab.plot(x,y)
pylab.show()
```

And I'm getting an error

```
only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

furthermore, when trying to do

```
y = numpy.sum(data[0], tuple(x))
```

because I looked up the function and saw that axis needed to be a tuple of ints, I get an error

```
ValueError: too many values for 'axis'
```

So basically I'm a bit lost, could use some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Run `help(numpy.sum)`. As you say, the problem is with what you're passing to the `axis` argument. It sounds like you're just guessing values to send it. You need to work out for yourself what the axis argument is for and then pass it the appropriate values, if any are needed.

Comment: Searched it, apparently axis has nothing to do with what I need. How do I create a function that is a sum of m elements? for each m between 1 and 1000

Comment: There is `numpy.add.accumulate` or the shortcut `numpy.cumsum`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `numpy.cumsum`. Furthermore, `axis` needs to be an integer, not an array or a tuple of an array (I think this explains the errors).

This should work:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab

data = np.random.binomial(1, 0.25, (100000,1000))
y = np.cumsum(data[:5, :], axis=1)  # cumulative sum of first 5 rows along the rows (axis=1)
pylab.plot(np.arange(1,y.shape[1]+1), y.T)
pylab.show()
```